# How to get region with lowest y value in the centroid

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary image that has two connected components. Both are fairly horizontal and one is on the top of the image and the other at the bottom. What I need to do is to extract only the top component which I want to do (or at least what I think is a good method) by taking the component with the lowest y value for the centroid (because MATLAB uses Java to show images, so the origin is at the top left) and erasing the other component. So far I've been able to use `regionprops` to find which region has the lowest y value for the centroid, but from there I'm not sure how to get a binary image back again with the component I want.

I've read in the documentation that `bwconncomp`, `labelmatrix`, and `ismember` are useful, but I'm not very sure how to use them well (or at all very much).

Comment: Do you have the `'PixelIdxList'` for the component you want to keep?

Comment: I have `PixelIdxList` for both components. I'm not sure how to use the information from `regionprops` to choose which `PixelIdxList` I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I just made up, but if there's a better or more elegant one I'd love to know about it!

P.S. `filtered` is my image

```
connComp = bwconncomp(filtered);

props = regionprops(filtered, 'Centroid');

justTop = zeros(size(filtered,1), size(filtered,2));
if props(1).Centroid(2) > props(2).Centroid(2)
    justTop(connComp.PixelIdxList{2}) = 1;
else
    justTop(connComp.PixelIdxList{1}) = 1;
end`
```

Comment: If there are more than the two regions, e.g. due to noise or something, this method will fail. To handle that, you would probably need to check the area of the detected region, and only compare the largest two regions or so. Otherwise this works nicely!

Comment: @hbaderts Thanks! That happened a while after I posted so I'm probably going to do something like that. Thanks for making it clearer though!

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks for sharing your answer here, so it can help others with the same problem in the future.